# django admin fails using TabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I built a simple django application and now have a really confusing error message. I think it's because of Tabularinline, but I use it properly  according [to this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
  class Person(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

  class Note(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()
```

**admin.py**

```
from addressbook.models import Person, Note
from django.contrib import admin


class NoteInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Note


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Person
    inlines = [NoteInline, ]


admin.site.register(Note, NoteInline)
admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

But I always get this error message:

> <class 'addressbook.admin.NoteInline'>: (admin.E202) 'addressbook.Note' has no ForeignKey to 'addressbook.Note'.

Which I would understand but why should have `Note` a reference to itself If I am using it from `Person`?

Comment: I don't think you need to separately register the `NoteInline` admin template. Just register the `PersonAdmin` template and that should include your `NoteInline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to separately register the `NoteInline` admin template. Just register the `PersonAdmin` template and that should include your `NoteInline`